# Pex and Moles For Commerical Purposes?

Tags: pex

Can Pex & Moles be used for Commercial Purposes.

If not, anyone has idea about when it will be for Commercial purpose.

I would like to know is it worth spending effort in a real business situation.

Thanks
Senthil Gandhi

Comment: Read the license agreement at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/license.aspx?

Answer (score 5):

**GET A LAWYER TO REVIEW YOUR DECISION**

**I am not a lawyer.**

As Jeff says [read the licenses yourself](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/license.aspx).

For the academic (free) license, it's clear: NO, it's for personal, non-commercial (or academic) use only.

> **Academic Release**
>
> License: MSR-LA
>   Microsoft Research License Agreement, Non-Commercial Use Only

The MSDN-license (paid for) has:

> **Visual Studio 2010 Power Tools**
>
> License: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Power Tools Software Terms

And downloading that license has:

> You may not
>
> - work around any technical limitations in the software;
> - reverse engineer, decompile or disassemble the software, except and only to the extent that applicable law expressly permits, despite this limitation;
> - make more copies of the software than specified in this agreement or allowed by applicable law, despite this limitation;
> - publish the software for others to copy;
> - rent, lease or lend the software; or
> - use the software for commercial software hosting services.

So, provided you comply with these items, it seems that you can use the power tools version for checking commercial work.